# SPServices - open "view item" modal

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, jquery, spservices

> NOTE: I'm begginer in SharePoint!

Ok so my situation is like that:
I have a list of Users, with multiple fields. For example there are fields like: *Name*, *Title*, *Office*, *Phone* and *Email*.

Pretty normal right? Right!

Now I'm using SPServices to put that in separate JS grid. But the problem is that I would like to open "View Item" modal from my JS grid. Is that possible?

Comment: ok i managed to open edit form by
http://myserver/sites/site/Lists/List/Editform.aspx?ID=22332

but how to open just "display view"

Comment: myserver/sites/site/Lists/List/Dispform.aspx?ID=22332

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track, so just a tip. Appending `&IsDlg=1` in the URL will ensure the navigational elements are hidden in the modal window.